# Laravel - How to make Cron Job work on my localhost Windows

Tags: laravel

I am consuming and external API using Guzzle. The I want to save into the database on my localhost before I eventually move it to the server.

Localhost:8888/myapp

It works on Postman and I could see the data when I used dd();

Console\Commands\UpdateCreateEmployee

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Employee;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Exception;
use GuzzleHttp\Client; 
use GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;


class UpdateCreateEmployee extends Command
{

    protected $signature = 'command:UpdateCreateEmployee';

    protected $description = 'Update or Create Employee Profile';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {

        $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;        

        $client = new Client();
    $res = $client->request('GET','https://api.apptest.net/staff', [
       'query' => ['key' => 'wwwwwwdddd']
    ])->getBody();

       $clientdatas = json_decode($res->getContents(), true);        

    foreach($clientdatas as $clientdata)
    {

        $employee = HrEmployee::updateOrCreate([
            'employee_code' => $clientdata->staff_id,
        ],
        [
            'username'                              => strtok($request->email_company, '@'),
            'first_name'                            => $clientdata->first_name,
            'last_name'                             => $clientdata->flast_name,
            'other_name'                            => $clientdata->middle_name,
            'date_of_birth'                         => Carbon::parse($clientdata['date_of_birth'])->toDateString(),
            'hr_status'                             => $clientdata->hr_status,
            'address'                               => $clientdata->address,
            'company_id'                            => 1,
            'country_name'                          => $clientdata->country,
            'email'                                 => $clientdata->email,

        ]);    

        //user
        $user = User::updateOrCreate([
            'email'                                 => $employee->email,

        ],
        [
            'username'                              => $employee->username,
            'password'                              => bcrypt("123456"),
            'first_name'                            => $employee->first_name,
            'last_name'                             => $employee->last_name,
        ]);

         $user->assignRole('Employee');

         $employee->update(['user_id' => $user->id]);        

    }
 } 

}
```

kernel

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{

    protected $commands = [
    'App\Console\Commands\UpdateCreateEmployee',
   ];

   protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
   {      
      $schedule->command('command:UpdateCreateEmployee')
              ->everyFifteenMinutes();          
   }

   protected function commands()
   {
      $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

      require base_path('routes/console.php');
   }
}
```

After fifteen minutes, I checked the database, there was nothing there.

How do I make it work on my localhost windows?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The native way to use cron jobs under Windows environment is Task Scheduler.
Make a new task to run every minute:

`Program script: path/to/your/php.exe`

`Add arguments: path/to/your/artisan schedule:run`

More information can be found here: https://quantizd.com/how-to-use-laravel-task-scheduler-on-windows-10/